# How to select a row by combination of two another cells wher target cell is null?

Tags: oracle

I would like to select a user by login, but in case if login is empty then select by combination of first and last name. E.g:

```
select * from user 
where login = 'criteria' // or if *login=null* then // where firstName || lastName = 'criteria'
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` (or Oracle's `nvl`) as follows:

```
select * from user 
where ('criterion' = coalesce(login, firstname)
    or 'criterion' = coalesce(login, lastname))
```

Another way:

```
select * from user 
where (login = 'criterion'
    or login is null and 'criterion' in (firstname, lastname))
```

NB: `user` is a reserved word in Oracle, so I assume in reality you have a different table name. If really it is `user`, you need to quote it: `"USER"`